# Where, other than home, can freelancers do their work?

Tags: working-from-home

When working on a solo project, sitting at home on your own can get a bit depressing after a while.

I can go to Starbucks, but feel a bit awkward sitting in Starbucks after an hour or so (even if I am buying plenty of coffee).

When all I need is space for a laptop and some wifi, what other sorts of places are good to go to, where I can experience a nice environment and be around other people?

Answer (score 5):

As a freelance, sometimes I work also at my clients's company offices, when I do a project for that specific client, if they have a free office or desk usually I can stay with them from a few hours up to a few days. 
While I work there I have people around, and the client is happy because we can interact more efficiently as I develop their project.

Of course I do that only with clients that I get along very well.

Other places where you can work being with others is the city or university library, parks when is summer, etc.

I wouldn't stay at Starbucks or places like that, I would feel very uncomfortable and is not a stimulating place.

Comment: Why "***university*** library"? I have worked out of my local, non-uni, library before now, often for weeks on end.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience,

- **Coffee shops** - I try all the coffee places in the area. There are some good small restaurants I discover too. I love it when I get to check out places other than Starbucks. Try it. You will be surprised at the places you'll find in there that are good for work.
- **Co-working spaces** - you can pay for co-working spaces in your area so you can also meet other freelancers and get to chat with them.
- **A friend's house** - Yes. This works. If you are really feeling lonely, go to a close friend's house. Just make sure you are not a burden at the moment. :) Let them know why you chose his/her place for work. Not only will this make you feel less lonely, you'd get to reconnect with them too.

Comment: +1 for co-working spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Trying not to sound like a plug for any particular place, but there are shared/collabrative workspaces popping up all over the place.

The one I am most familiar with is [Gangplank](http://gangplankhq.com)  It is a location you can just drop into an do your work.  There are no fees and you don't have to share anything.  However the idea is basically that while you are sitting there doing your work, you have a casual conversation with someone else doing their work and you both discover and untapped opportunity and come together to fulfill it and make more $$$.

My local group provides basic desk/tables, free internet and free printing, and a free conference room - all designed to lure unsuspecting people into their midst in order to foster new business opportunities! These facilities have been donated by people/businesses with no expectation that you have to repay other than by being open to talking to and/or helping other people.

For more general ideas, google collaborative works spaces in your area and see what pops up.  Also check up on any business incubator groups that may also have workspaces.  There are also some subscription based groups doing the same thing, and I would also check into any maker groups in your area as well.

Comment: Coworking spaces are good, but not for everyone, I really, really hate chit-chats.

Comment: @RomanKo the OP wants to be around other people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is standard, but the Barnes & Noble near us is open until 11pm and has free Wi-Fi. I like the atmosphere a lot better than Starbucks, and you'll have plenty to read on your break.